# Other variants of the Shelah's Weak Hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, cardinal-arithmetic, pcf-theory

The paper

> Menachem Kojman. *Splitting families of sets in ZFC*.
>   arXiv:[1209.1307](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1307)

presents these variants of the Shelah's Weak Hypothesis:

> $$
> (\textrm{SWH}_n) \textrm{ There are no infinite } \nu \textrm{ and } \rho
> \textrm{ such that } \beth_n (\nu) < \rho < \beth_{\omega} (\nu) \textrm{ and }
> $$
>   $$
> \mathcal{F} = \{ A_{\alpha} : \alpha < \rho^+ \} \subseteq {[\rho]}^{\rho}
> \textrm{ satisfies } |A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta}| < \nu \textrm{ for }
> \alpha < \beta < \rho^+ .
> $$

Is this, for a fixed $n \in \omega$, equivalent with the following, for some cardinal $\mu$?

$$
\textrm{For every infinite cardinal } \kappa,
|\{ \lambda \in \kappa : \lambda \textrm{ is a singular cardinal and} \operatorname{pp} (\lambda) \geq \kappa \}| \leq \mu .
$$

The last statement, when $\mu = \aleph_0$, is the "standard version" of SWH.